# Every subspace $W$ of $F^n$ is the space of solutions of some system of homogeneous linear equations $AX=0$.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, group-theory

From Artin's Algebra:

---

The definition of isomorphism given in the book:

> An isomorphism $\varphi$ from a vector space $V$ to a vector space $V'$ both over the same field $F$, is a bijective map $\varphi:V\rightarrow V'$ compatible with the laws of composition, that is, a bijective map satisfying
>
> $$(a)\space\varphi(v+v')=\varphi(v)+\varphi(v')\space\text{and}\space(b)\space\varphi(cv)=c\space\varphi(v),$$
> for all $v,v'\in V$ and for all $c\in F$.

---

> Question:
>
> Let $V=F^n$ be the space of column vectors. Prove that every subspace $W$ of $V$ is the space of solutions of some system of homogeneous linear equations $AX=0$.

**Note:** We are *not* allowed to use the concept of **basis, span** etc.

**Attempt:**

First I thought if I change the definition of isomorphism by $\varphi$ is any map(not only bijective), we must get the definition of homomorphism.

Now choose any subspace $W$ of a vector space and consider the map

$$\varphi_0:W\rightarrow \{0\}$$

Then $\varphi_0$ is a homomorphism and surjective. Then we can define $\varphi^{-1}_0(0)=\{v\in W: \varphi_0(v)=0\}=W$

Then how to show $\varphi_0(v)=Av$?

Comment: You haven't defined $\phi_0$; you can't just say it's a linear map.