# For $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $W \leq \mathbb{F}^n$, there exists a homogeneous system of linear equations whose solution space is $W$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, systems-of-equations

> For $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $W \leq \mathbb{F}^n$, show that there exists a homogeneous system of linear equations whose solution space is $W$.

Here's my work:

Since $W \leq \mathbb{F}^n$, $k = dim(W) \leq dim(\mathbb{F}^n)$. Let's say that $\{w_1,w_2,...,w_k\}$ is a basis of $W$. Now, construct a matrix $A$ (of size $k \times n$) such that its rows are elements from the basis of $W$, stacked together. The row space of $A$ is $W$, so the row space of its row-echelon form is $W$ too. At this point, *I'm stuck!* I'm trying to come up with a homogeneous system with the help of $A$, though there may exist other easier ways of approaching this problem.

Could someone show me the light?

P.S. $W \leq \mathbb{F}^n$ *stands for* $W$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{F}^n$.

P.P.S. Isn't this equivalent to saying that $W$ is the null-space of some matrix? Can we go ahead along these lines, and construct a matrix $P$ such that $Pw = 0$ for all $w \in W$?

Comment: Here's a related question with no answer, so *I had to post a new one*: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2401956/every-subspace-w-of-fn-is-the-space-of-solutions-of-some-system-of-homogene

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured something out myself, so I'll post it. Let $\{w_1,w_2,...,w_k\}$ be a basis of $W$ and let's extend this set to a basis of $\mathbb{F}^n$, to obtain $\{w_1,w_2,...,w_n\}$.

Now, if we define a linear map  $T: \mathbb{F^n} \to \mathbb{F^n}$, such that $T(w_i) = 0$ for $1 \leq i \leq k$ and $T(w_j) = w_j$ for $k+1 \leq j \leq n$. As a side-note, we can see that $\rm{dim}(\rm{null}(T)) = k$ & $\rm{dim}(\rm{range}(T)) = n-k$. Consider the matrix $A$ corresponding to this linear map $T$. Clearly, $Ax = 0$ is the desired system of homogeneous equations!

It remains to verify that this construction of $A$ actually works, i.e. the solution space of $Ax = 0$ is $W$ and only $W$ - but I'll not include that here for brevity.

Comment: I like it.  Seems to be about what I was trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

Consider a basis of $W$ to be the vectors $\{w_1, \ldots, w_k\}$. Now take the homogeneous system with matrix the row vectors $(w_1, \ldots, w_k)$. If you take the space of solutions of this system and find a basis for it then you got your desired matrix.

We can make this a bit more explicit. The matrix with the row vectors $(w_1, \ldots, w_k)$ has size $k \times n$.  Say it is in block form $(A,B)$ where $A$ is non-singular $k\times k$, and $B$ is $k \times n-k$.  Solving the homogeneous system given by the matrix $(A,B)$ expresses the first $k$ components in terms of the the last $n-k$ components ( invert $A$, ...). To find the basis for the space of solutions, just check that
$$[A,B]\cdot \begin{bmatrix}-A^{-1}B \\ I_{n-k} \end{bmatrix} =0_{k,n-k}$$

Therefore, we can take the transpose of the matrix $\begin{bmatrix}-A^{-1}B \\ I_{n-k} \end{bmatrix} $ and find a desired homogenous system.

Comment: What's the homogeneous system you're referring to? $(A,B)x = 0$? If yes, I can't seem to follow from there.

Comment: Yes, that is the system. Try to take a "concrete" example. Solve the system and see what is the general solution.

Comment: Are we using the fact that the row-space and nullspace of a matrix are orthogonal? Nonetheless, could you add more details?

Comment: Yes, they are orthogonal, it's fairly obvious.

Comment: $[A,B]\cdot \begin{bmatrix}-A^{-1}B \\ I_{n-k} \end{bmatrix} =0_{k,n-k} \iff \begin{bmatrix}-A^{-1}B \\ I_{n-k} \end{bmatrix}^T \cdot [A,B]^T = 0_{k,n-k}^T$ - is this what you're saying? How does this help and what's $0_{k,n-k}$?

Comment: It helps in producing the null space of the matrix $[A,B]$.     $0_{k.n-k}$ is the $0$ matrix of size $k\times n-k$.  It could help you to consider the particular case $k=1$.

Answer (score 1):

Extend $\{w_1,\dots,w_k\}$ to a basis $\beta=\{w_1,\dots,w_n\}$ for $\Bbb F^n$.

Now define the matrix $A$ whose first $n-k$ columns are $\{w_{k+1},\dots,w_n\}$. Fill the rest in with zeros.

Use the basis $\beta$ for the domain, and the standard basis for the range.  So, we need to multiply $A$ by the (inverse of the) transition matrix, whose columns are the elements of $\beta$.  Call that matrix $B$.

The homogeneous system corresponding to $AB^{-1}$ has solution space equal to $W$.

Comment: Could you check my answer, and let me know if it correctly builds upon your initial construction?

Comment: Congrats on solving your problem.  I'm still thinking about whether my answer works.  Maybe so if we use the standard basis for the range and the basis consisting of the $w_i$ for the domain.  It may then coincide with your answer.    I didn't mention anything about a basis in my answer, so the standard basis is implied.  It probably needs to be adjusted.

Comment: Thank you! I'm thinking about the matrix $A$ defined here, too - and how it may work.

Answer (score 1):

Consider $W$ as normal subgroup of $\mathbb F^n$ (it's normal because $\mathbb F^n$ as a group is abelian). Then we can define the quotient group $\mathbb F^n/W$ with the equivalence classes $x+W$, with $x\in\mathbb F^n$, as its elements.

First, I assert that $\Bbb F^n/W$ works as a vector space over $\Bbb F$ (you can skip this part if you already know it). Given $x,y\in\Bbb F^n$ and $\alpha, \beta\in\Bbb F$:

1. It's an abelian group for the sum defined as $(x+W)+(y+W)=(x+y)+W$ (we know this from group theory).
2. We can define the scalar product $\alpha(x+W)=\alpha x+W$. For this to be well defined we have to show that if $x+W=y+W$ then $\alpha x+W=\alpha y+W$. Indeed, we have that $x-y\in W$, so there is some $w\in W$ such that $x-y=w$, and thus $\alpha(x-y)=\alpha x-\alpha y=\alpha w$. Since $W$ is a vector subspace, $\alpha w\in W$, so $\alpha x+W=\alpha y+W$.
3. $\alpha(\beta(x+W))=\alpha(\beta x+W)=\alpha\beta x+W=(\alpha\beta)x+W=\alpha\beta(x+W)$.
4. If we name $1$ the identity element for the product in $\Bbb F$, $1(x+W)=1x+W=x+W$.
5. $\alpha((x+W)+(y+W))=\alpha((x+y)+W)=\alpha(x+y)+W=(\alpha x+W)+(\alpha y+W)=\alpha(x+W)+\alpha(y+W)$.
6. $(\alpha+\beta)(x+W)=(\alpha+\beta)x+W=(\alpha x+\beta x)+W=(\alpha x+W)+(\beta x+W)$.

---

Now let's consider the canonical projection $\pi:\Bbb F^n\to\Bbb F^n/W$ given by $\pi(x)=x+W$. This is a linear map, since $\pi(\alpha x+\beta y)=(\alpha x +\beta y)+W=(\alpha x+W)+(\beta y+W)=\alpha(x+W)+\beta(x+W)=\alpha\pi(x)+\beta\pi(y)$.

We can use the fact that [any linear transformation between two finite dimensional vector spaces can be represented by a matrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1785040/can-any-linear-transformation-be-represented-by-a-matrix) (the proof in the link uses $\Bbb R$ as field, but it can be easily generalized). In our case we know $\Bbb F^n/W$ is finite dimensional because $\pi$ is a surjective linear map (and linear maps preserve linear dependence).

Finally, we know that $\ker(\pi)=W$, so taking the matrix representation you can represent the linear map's kernel as a system of homogeneous linear equations whose solution is the nullspace of the matrix, this is, $W$.

Note: Now we know $\ker(\pi)=W$ we can use the rank-nullity theorem to get the dimension of $\mathbb F^n/W$, since $\text{Im}(\pi)=W$ (remember $\pi$ is onto): $\dim(\mathbb F^n)=\dim(\text{Im}(\pi))+\dim(\ker(\pi))=\dim(\mathbb F^n/W)+\dim(W)\Rightarrow\mbox{$\dim(\mathbb F^n/W)=\dim(\mathbb F^n)-\dim(W)$}.$